# Random annoying error System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2005

On occasions I keep getting the following annoying error, it doesn't happen all the time just seems to be random:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'. at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
```

Here is the code that seems to generate the error:

```
public vwStaff GetUserDetails(string init) {
    //Just to check if the initials are empty, if they are make an attempt to get them again
    //Just put in place as an extra test, but not making any difference, will remove shortly
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(init) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(init)) {
        init = F.GetUserInitials();
    }

    using (GlobalDataContext db = DataHelper.GetDataContext()) {
        return db.vwStaffs.FirstOrDefault(w => w.StaffInitials == init);
    }
}
```

vwStaff is a standard MsSQL2005 View and does nothing fancy

The F.GetUserInitials, is just a quick helper method:

```
    public static string GetUserInitials() {
        string userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToLower();
        return userId.Remove(0, userId.LastIndexOf("\\", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
    }
```

Everything as far as I can see is a string, so no idea where the Int32 is coming into it.  I've checked the database against the code mapping and all fields match.

Can anyone suggest where I can look next.

Comment: either here `init = F.GetUserInitials();` or here `db.vwStaffs.FirstOrDefault(w => w.StaffInitials == init);`, you have wrong dataType returned or stored in your database table

Comment: That's the thing it's not.  Everything is text.  Have checked the code and everything is a string, cannot find any reference to an int in these areas.  The helper method is returning a string. w.StaffInitials is a varchar(4) field. init is a string!?